# Where does a rails (3) application define what is supposed to happen in activesupport-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, activerecord

I generated a model file but then chose to let it single table inherit from another model. I had to run no migration, because the columns all were already there.

Now whenever I want to run tests, I get complaints that the table for the model does not exist.

So I have Product < Article < ActiveRecord::Base, product has no own table (does not have it in the schema neither), but still I get

```
test_should_update_article(ArticlesControllerTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: products: DELETE FROM "products" WHERE 1=1
    AR/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:202:in `rescue in log'
    AR/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:194:in `log'
    AR/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:135:in `execute'
    AR/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:269:in `update_sql'
    AR/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:139:in `update_sql'
    AR/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:274:in `delete_sql'
    AR/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:145:in `delete_sql'
    AR/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:54:in `delete'
    AR/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:16:in `delete'
    AR/active_record/fixtures.rb:551:in `delete_existing_fixtures'
    AR/active_record/fixtures.rb:513:in `block (4 levels) in create_fixtures'
    AR/active_record/fixtures.rb:513:in `each'
    AR/active_record/fixtures.rb:513:in `block (3 levels) in create_fixtures'
    AR/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
    AR/active_record/fixtures.rb:512:in `block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
    AR/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:104:in `disable_referential_integrity'
    AR/active_record/fixtures.rb:503:in `block in create_fixtures'
    AS/active_support/benchmarkable.rb:55:in `silence'
    AR/active_record/fixtures.rb:502:in `create_fixtures'
    AR/active_record/fixtures.rb:961:in `load_fixtures'
    AR/active_record/fixtures.rb:926:in `setup_fixtures'
    AS/active_support/callbacks.rb:419:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
    AS/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:34:in `run'
```

AR is a shorthand for /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/AS/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/AS/activerecord-3.0.0.rc/lib
AS for /Users/janlimpens/.rvm/AS/ruby-1.9.2-rc2@rails3/AS/activesupport-3.0.0.rc/lib/

I wonder what I could do...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Single Table Inheritance, as Product model inherits from Article Model.

For this to work you need a "type" column in Article Table, which will be filled by "Product"
or any other class that inherits Article model.

Add that and the sql query would look like

> select * from articles where articles.type = "Product"

Comment: There already is such a column and persisting Products (the type column reads 'Product') works. This query must come from somewhere else...

Comment: some place which did not automatically learn that product is an article now and not an activerecord::base

Comment: Hmm.. Some problem with the Test, Can you paste the test code here. as well. Also, when you write controller tests decouple it from models using mocks and stubs :)